# React query - All queries/mutations in one file OR one query file per component?

Tags: javascript, react-query

I have a huge component with 15 subcomponents, each of them have 1/2 queries, and some of them have 1 or 2 mutations.

Some queries are shared between components, but some of them are specific to that component.

Right now I have all mutations + queries in a separate file, as functions that return the query/mutation, and all the fetching functions.

Should I only keep the shared queries in this file? And move the specific queries/mutations to a file inside each component file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I will keep the actions, etc in files closest to the component it is used in, or shared across. The reason is that if and when you decide to move or delete those components, it is extremely easy to garbage collect the redundant code, as well as general maintenance of code beforehand - you just delete the folder and know that it's dependencies are never used anywhere else other than deeper within the component.

### Example:

```
- /BlogPost/
  - /components/
    - /BlogPostSocialMedia/
      - /index.jsx
  - /index.jsx
```

Assuming the above structure - lets say I have a component called `BlogPost`, which contained a sub-component `BlogSocialMedia`.

If the `BlogSocialMedia` had an action that is used only within that component, I would place it in a file within the `/BlogSocialMedia` directory. Maybe `/BlogPost/components/BlogSocialMedia/actions.js`?

However, if there was a query or action that was used by both the `BlogPost` **and** the `BlogPostSocial` component, I would place it one directory back, in `/BlogPost/actions.js`

Hopefully, you can see how this keeps your components nice and "packaged", and makes it much easier to maintain, move, and delete it in the future. The alternative is that you find yourself with a single file as you mention, which is extremely difficult to identify what code is stale and what isn't, and almost impossible to move around if you need to.

On a final note: Read into and understand the principle of [Single Responsibility][1]. It is far from optimal to have a single file which is responsible for **so many** different actions.

[1]: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/solid-principles-single-responsibility-principle-explained/#:~:text=The%20Single%20Responsibility%20Principle%20(SRP,only%20one%20reason%20to%20change%22.